# How to Search datetime in Sql server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

i am having problem with a sql search . i am trying to search with the help of datetime because in my project time is very important. when i use query like this

```
where registration_date = '2014-06-19 00:12:08.940'
```

it does works but as soon as i try to search using

```
where registration_date like '2014-06-19%'
```

i get no results. because i want to search for all the registration taken place on a specific date including time, i am assuming that i dont know the specific time...

Comment: `registration_date >= '2014-06-19' AND registration_date < '2014-06-20'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to cast to date to compare two dates on equality. eg

```
CAST(registration_date AS DATE) = CAST('2014-06-19' AS DATE)
```

An alternative:

```
DECLARE @DateToFilter DATE = (CAST('2014-06-19' AS DATE))    
[..]
WHERE registration_date >= @DateToFilter
AND registration_date < DATEADD(d, 1, @DateToFilter)
```

EDIT:
Regarding performance, and *assuming* an index exists on the date column, the index can be used in both cases (yes, CAST(x AS DATE) is SARGable). There is a very interesting analysis on the performance differences [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51340/should-i-join-datetime-to-a-date-using-cast-or-range) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). As always, test.

Comment: @g2server thanks (cast) has done the job but one more question how can i add "between" in your above query can you please modify with a "between"

Comment: Avoid `CAST` in favour of specifying a range, if you have an index on `registration_date` SQL Server can efficiently seek to that range.

Answer (score 3):

Simply search for everything that's at least on or after that date, and earlier than the next day.

```
    registration_date >= '2014-06-19'
AND registration_date < '2014-06-20'
```

Answer (score 1):

Search with intervals:

```
WHERE registration_date >= '2014-06-19 00:00:00' AND registration_date < '2014-06-20 00:00:00'
```

When you search for a specific time, use the same value in both conditions, when you search for a day, use the above format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
where convert(date,registration_date) = '2014-06-19'
```

It works for between also

Answer (score 0):

Eigher you cast both part, so all data which have same date find like

```
CAST(registration_date AS DATE) = CAST('2014-06-19' AS DATE)
or 
Convert(varchar(10), registration_date,103) = Convert(varchar(10),'2014-06-19' ,103)
```

or you can search as above date range

```
 registration_date 
 between cast( getdate() as date ) and
 dateadd(dd, 1, cast( getdate() as date ))
```